# Can't setup Karma and Jasmine for Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I've tried several tutorials and looked at many of the solutions provided here. I am new to Angular and currently trying to set up testing for a rather big SPA.

Following [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/testing-angularjs-with-jasmine-and-karma-part-1) tutorial I have completed:

- Angularjs application setup
- Karma setup
- Our first test

The karma config file is basically the default content, with some references in files and exclude:

```
// list of files/patterns to load in the browser
 files: [
    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'app/app.js',
    'JavaScript.spec.js'
],
```

I reinstalled the entire test implementation and now the simple test works again. But trying to write a test for a controller does not work:

here is the error message
[image: error output]

I changed the path referencing the bower_components and app files in the karma config file. Now the shell running karma returns an error message from the app.js file, saying:

```
   Uncaught ReferenceError: Logging is not defined
```

Writing a test identical to the one from doucmentation, gives the following error:

[image: error message]

Here is the test code:

```
describe('nyKladdController', function () {
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var $controller; 
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
        $controller = _$controller_; 
    }));


    describe('$scope.mixTable', function () {
        it('is false', function () {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('nyKladdController', { $scope: $scope }); 
            expect($scope.mixTable).toBeFalsy();
        });
    }); 
});
```

As you can see from the error message: after the app module, the test file start loading the app dependencies. Here is the app.js file:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app', [
        'ngAnimate', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngResource', 'ngMessages',
        'AdalAngular', 'config', 'angular.filter',
        'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.mask', 'ui.select', 'ui.validate',
        'angular-loading-bar', 'ui.tree', 'ui.tree-filter', 'checklist-model'
    ]);
})();
```

In other words: how can i get my tests to load the app dependecies as well.

Comment: Try to remove your `bower_components` and `node_modules` folders and reinstall all your dependencies.

Comment: I just did and the simple test works again

Comment: Did it work.. or not.

Comment: not, it's still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to load in all the app dependencies from app.js in to karma.config file. Now the files array in karma config looks like this:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    //bower modules
    './bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    './bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    './bower_components/angular-ui-mask/src/mask.js',
    './bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js',
    './bower_components/angular-ui-tree-filter/dist/angular-ui-tree-filter.js',
    './bower_components/angular-ui-tree/dist/angular-ui-tree.js',
    './bower_components/angular-ui-validate/dist/validate.js',
    './bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js',
    // node modules
    './node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
    './node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js', 
    './node_modules/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
    './node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource.js', 
    './node_modules/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
    './node_modules/adal-angular/dist/adal-angular.min.js',
    './node_modules/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.js',
    './node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js', 
    './node_modules/bower-config/lib/Config.js',
    './node_modules/checklist-model/checklist-model.js',
    //app file
    './app/app.js',
    './app/common/config/config.js',
    //test files etc..
    'JavaScript.spec.js',
    './app/produkt/ny/controllers/*.js' // tester å hente inn controller som refereres i test filen
],
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because Karma is loading the source files in the wrong order. For Angular to work properly, each module must be loaded before any component, services, etc. associated with that module.

To fix this, you can change your Karma configuration to ensure your module files are loaded first.

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    '../../bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    '../../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'app/**/*.module.js',
    'app/**/*.js'
],
```

This is assuming you're using some kind of naming convention for angular modules (like *.module.js as in the above example). Otherwise you'll have to list the paths to the modules individually.

Comment: There are no .module.js files in the project. Shouldn't I only need to load the files i need for testing in the karma.config file?

Comment: The file where you declare your angular module, like this: `angular.module('app', [])` is your module file. That needs to be loaded before any other of your angular files by Karma. Some use the naming convension `app.module.js` for this (and other) module files, to easily distinguish them.

Comment: I understand, now i added the app.js file at the top of files: , but I am still having the same issue

Comment: Try to include the `angular.mocks.js` dependency as well. Check my updated answer. Your path might be different though, so do double check.

Comment: angular.mocks.js is already included. yes I will double check my path

Comment: It isn't in the list of files you've shown in your question.

Comment: it was referenced under exclude, but i moved it to files. It didn't help

Answer (score 0):

add `beforeEach(module("your-module-name"));` => your angular application name from app.js"

```
describe('check a controller', function () {

    beforeEach(module("your module name")); // I think you missed this.

    var scope, checkController; 

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.new(); 

        checkController = function () {
            return $controller('nyKladdController', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        }; 
    }));

    it('has a dummy spec to test 2 + 2', function () {
        // An intentionally failing test. No code within expect() will never equal 4.
        expect(2 + 2).toEqual(4);
    });

});
```

karma.conf

```
files: [     // sample order. Include your files accordingly
            'src/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
            'src/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
             // some sample libraries 
            'src/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js',
            'src/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
            'src/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js',
            'src/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js',
            'src/bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js',

            'src/app/app.js',
            'src/app/**/*.js',
            'tests/unit/**/*.spec.js'
        ],
exclude: []
```

Comment: I added the line, but the reference error is still the same. The test i have written now is identical to the test example on the angularjs documentation. This means that I am missing som import under files in the karma.config file

Comment: did you check the repo I gave? @ØysteinSeel. Can you share your sample test via github

Comment: yes I've been under /tests/unit and looked at the files, I am referincing the module name in the same way in my solution